# How to get ip address of a client that connect to a websocket server in FastAPI?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, fastapi

I'm newbie in FastAPI. I have a websocket server in 127.0.0.1:8000/abcd and ConnectionManager Object.

```
class ConnectionManager:
def __init__(self):
    self.active_connections: List[WebSocket] = []

async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    self.active_connections.append(websocket)

def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
    self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.send_text(message)

async def broadcast(self, message: str):
    for connection in self.active_connections:
        await connection.send_text(message)

manager = ConnectionManager()
```

And the websocket server:

```
@router.websocket("/abcd")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
```

How can I get the IP Address of the Client Websocket Connection? And How can I change the active_connections to a Dictionary with the key is IP Address and value is the websocket? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Information from the initial HTTP request for creating the websocket is stored in the Websocket object and can be introspected.  Starlette gives a few helper methods for retrieving this information.

```py
@router.websocket("/abcd")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    client_host = websocket.client.host
    await manager.connect(websocket)
```

For more information you can see the Starlette Websocket source:

https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/5ee04ef9b1bc11dc14d299e6c855c9a3f7d5ff16/starlette/websockets.py#L20

and the source for it's super class HTTPConnection:

https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/5ee04ef9b1bc11dc14d299e6c855c9a3f7d5ff16/starlette/requests.py#L57